# required drop-down lists with Save Button

Tags: javascript

I have 2 required drop-down lists,this is my try but it doesn't work when I click on the "Save" Button:

```
<div>
   <button class="btn btn-action" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</div>

<form>
  <div class="row">
  <select required>
    <option ng-repeat="pi in listProduitAvailable" value="{{pi.id}}">{{pi.reference}}</option>
  </select>
   <select required>
    <option ng-repeat="pi in listProduitAvailable" value="{{pi.id}}">{{pi.reference}}</option>
  </select>                                                             
 </div>
</form>
```

the save method:

```
$scope.save= function() {
                    $scope.creerGamme();
            }
```

how can I correct my code please
thanks for help

Comment: actually your question is not clear , what you want on save button with dropdown list , is your button save function hit ? $scope.save() = function() {alert('test');
                    $scope.creerGamme();
            }

Comment: Please refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide necessary details. Also you can use this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ytwbdxns/) to give a working demo.

Comment: Sir thanks for your reply,my "Save" method works perfectly,the problem is with the required drop-down lists,the client must select an option before the click on the "Save" method,which is does't work for me when I click on the button and forget to choose an option from the select input